# POST data via Ajax to a Yandex Payment Gateway

Tags: php, ajax, post, yandex

I have a form that's posted like so;

```
<form action="https://money.yandex.ru/eshop.xml" method="post">
    <input name="shopId" value="1234" type="hidden"/>
    <input name="scid" value="4321" type="hidden"/>
    <input name="sum" value="100.50" type="hidden">
    <input name="customerNumber" value="abc000" type="hidden"/>
    <input name="shopArticleId" value="567890" type="hidden"/>
    <input name="paymentType" value="AC" type="hidden"/>
    <input name="orderNumber" value="abc1111111" type="hidden"/>
    <input name="cps_phone" value="79110000000" type="hidden"/>
    <input name="cps_email" value="user@domain.com" type="hidden"/>
  <input type="submit" value="Pay"/>
</form>
```

This is an example from [the Yandex docs](https://tech.yandex.com/money/doc/payment-solution/payment-form/payment-form-http-docpage/). But my own form will look similar. The question I have is, how do I test that the `sum` (amount of money) is the same as the total cost of the items?

For other payment gateways, I have managed to achieve this using ajax. So first submit a query to my database, and then redirect (although that's probably not the right word) to the payment gateway. And then when the response comes back, I can compare it to the record in my database.

But how would that work here? Their gateway doesn't seem to account for that kind of token handling.

Forgetting about gateway specifics, is it possible to just "post" data using ajax?

***UPDATE***

What about using this?

```
$.ajax({ 
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'https://money.yandex.ru/eshop.xml',
        data: {
            shopId: shopId,
            scid: scid,
            etc: etc
        }
    }
```

Comment: Use dataType: 'jsonp' in jQuery AJAX (for Cross Domain).

Comment: @Ahsan but this is XML. Will it not conflict?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. just 'post' data through AJAX is possible. Here's a little basic example.

```
<form id="exampleForm">

    <input name="name" value="A random name" />
    <input type="submit" value="Post through AJAX">

</form>

<script>
    $( "#exampleForm" ).submit(function( event ) {

      // Stop default form submit
      event.preventDefault();

      //Serialize the form data
      var formData = $(this).serializeArray();

      // Send the data using post
      var posting = $.post( 'HERE THE DESTINATION URL OF THE POST', formData, function(responseData
      {
        //An action when the POST request is done
      }));

    });
</script>
```

*Do not forget to include the JQuery libary.*

**UPDATE**
For cross-browsing AJAX request you need to use the `dataType` 'jsonp'. According to your sample request you can try this:

```
$.ajax({

    url: 'https://money.yandex.ru/eshop.xml',
    data: {
        shopId: shopId,
        scid: scid,
        etc: etc
    },
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function() 
    { 
        alert('Success callback'); 
    },
    error: function() 
    { 
        alert('Error callback'); 
    }
});
```

Comment: What is the difference between your suggestion and something like what's in my update? Something similar is used in another part of the code base but the url is to something internal.

Comment: Actually nothing, but i think you didn't updated the question when i posted this answer. Or maybe i forgot to refresh it.

Comment: I get an error XMLHttpRequest cannot load No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present. So there is a deeper problem to solve here.

Comment: Updated my answerl, can you try that?